# Handlebars condition based on lookup

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I have the following data structure:

```
{
    things: [
        "desk",
        "chair",
        "pen",
        "book",
        "lamp"
    ],
    owners: [
        "Julia",
        "Sandra",
        "John",
        "Paul"
    ]
}
```

**What's working:**

This `handleblars` template:

```
{{#each things}}
    <p>This {{this}} belongs to {{lookup ../owners @index}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

Correctly outputs:

```
This desk belongs to Julia
This chair belongs to Sandra
This pen belongs to John
This book belongs to Paul
This lamp belongs to
```

**What's not working:**

Now, I'd like to add a condition because the last `thing` might not have an `owner`. The template would then look something like:

```
{{#each things}}
    {{#if lookup ../owners @index}}
        <p>This {{this}} belongs to {{lookup ../owners @index}}</p>
    {{else}}
        <p>...But this {{this}} belongs to nobody</p>
    {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

And the ouput:

```
This desk belongs to Julia
This chair belongs to Sandra
This pen belongs to John
This book belongs to Paul
...But this lamp belongs to nobody
```

Unfortunately, this `{{#if lookup ../owners @index}}` thing doesn't work.

**My question: is it possible to achieve this with built-in Handlebars helpers, or do I have to write a custom helper?**

Comment: Seems like the answer to your question is still a 'no'. Please let me know if you managed to solve this or whether you have written a custom Handlebars helper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will be better if you were to change your data structure, for instance like this:

```
[
        {   
            thing:    "desk",
            owner: "Julia"
        },
        {   
            thing: "chair",
            owner:"Sandra"
        },
        {   
            thing:  "pen",
            owner:  "John"},
        {   
            thing:  "book",
            owner:  "Paul"},
        { 
            thing:  "lamp"
        }
]
```

then your handlebar template will look like

```
{{#each this}}
  {{#if this.owner}}
    <p>This {{this.thing}} belongs to {{ this.owner}}</p>
{{else}}
 <p>...But this {{this.thing}} belongs to nobody</p>
{{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

this will output (I ran it on http://tryhandlebarsjs.com/)

```
<p>This desk belongs to Julia</p>
<p>This chair belongs to Sandra</p>
<p>This pen belongs to John</p>
<p>This book belongs to Paul</p>
<p>...But this lamp belongs to nobody</p>
```

Using handlebars helpers may look good to you, but moving logic from handlebars to javascript **will** be better in long run.

Answer (score 8):

You can indeed do just what you're trying to do, using subexpressions:

`{{#if (lookup ../owners @index)}}`

works like a charm.
(source: [Handlebars website](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/expressions.html#subexpressions))

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is a 'no' if you want to nest Handlebars `lookup` with an `if`.

But here, if you want to omit the last `thing` (or n things) which don't have an `owner`, you may reverse check the `#each` like below,

```
{{#each owners}}
  <p>This {{lookup ../things @index}} belongs to {{this}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

Which outputs,

```
<p>This desk belongs to Julia</p>
<p>This chair belongs to Sandra</p>
<p>This pen belongs to John</p>
<p>This book belongs to Paul</p>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an alternate solution by writing a custom helper, `isIndexExist`.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("isIndexExist", function(array, value, options) {
  return value < array.length ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
});
```

And in the template, you can write,

```
{{#each things}}
  {{#isIndexExist ../owners @index}}
    <p>This {{this}} belongs to {{lookup ../owners @index}}</p>
  {{else}}
    <p>...But this {{this}} belongs to nobody</p>
  {{/isIndexExist}}
{{/each}}
```

Hope this helps.