# Refering to 'this' from handlebars each helper within handlebars-helper inArray block helper

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

I'm using Node.js, express, [`handlebars`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/handlebars) and [`handlebars-helpers`](https://github.com/helpers/handlebars-helpers).

When using `res.render()` I pass two objects to my Handlebars template, the objects are as follows:

```
var searchParams = {a: ['Apples']}
var searchFields = {a: ['Apples', 'Pears', 'Oranges']}
```

I then wish to create checkboxes on the pages using `searchFields`. When a checkbox variable is within the corresponding `searchParams` variable I want the checkbox to be checked by default.

I'm attempting to use the [`handlebars-helpers`](https://github.com/helpers/handlebars-helpers) helper function [`inArray`](https://github.com/helpers/handlebars-helpers#inArray) to achieve this using the following in the template:

```
<form>
{{#each searchFields.a}}
<label>
<input name="only_a_test" value="{{this}}" type="checkbox" 
  {{#inArray searchParams.a this}}
  checked
  {{else}}
  {{/inArray}}
  >
{{this}}
</label>
{{/each}}
</form>
```

However this throws the error:

Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

```
TypeError: .../web/views/search.hbs: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at Object.indexOf (.../web/node_modules/handlebars-utils/index.js:82:31)
    at String.helpers.inArray (.../web/node_modules/handlebars-helpers/lib/array.js:225:26)
    at eval (eval at createFunctionContext (.../web/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/compiler/javascript-compiler.js:254:23), <anonymous>:10:91)
    at Object.prog [as inverse] (.../web/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/runtime.js:219:12)
    at Object.utils.value (.../web/node_modules/handlebars-utils/index.js:237:50)
    at String.helpers.eq (.../web/node_modules/handlebars-helpers/lib/comparison.js:170:15)
    at eval (eval at createFunctionContext (.../web/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/compiler/javascript-compiler.js:254:23), <anonymous>:5:84)
    at prog (.../web/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/runtime.js:219:12)
    at execIteration (.../web/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/helpers/each.js:51:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (.../web/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/helpers/each.js:61:13)
```

I can't quite grok what's going on, I suspect it's having an issue with using `this` in the `inArray` block helper - it perhaps isn't seeing the underlying string?

Comment: You may consider changing your data structure. Refer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34483744/handlebars-condition-based-on-lookup/48856772#48856772

Comment: I don't think you need `{{else}}` block in `{{#inArray ...}} ......{{/inArray}}`

Comment: Did you try `{{#inArray ../searchParams.a this}}`? Did it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative approach, you can consider writing you own custom 'Handlebars 
 Helper' as below,

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("isInArray", function(array, value) {
  if (array.indexOf(value) != -1) {
    return "checked";
  }
});
```

> Or an optimised way

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("isInArray", function(array, value) {
  return array.indexOf(value) != -1 ? 'checked' : '';
});
```

And call it in your template file as,

```
<input name="only_a_test" value="{{this}}" type="checkbox" {{isInArray ../b this}}>
```

[PEN](https://codepen.io/gibinealias/pen/OQQMzM). Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you explain why in the handlebars template you have `../b`? This works thanks, I just don't understand the `../` notation, perhaps I'm missing something from the handlebars internals as it doesn't work without it.

Comment: As you could see in the PEN, the array name is kept as `a` and `b` (`var data = {
  a: ["Apples", "Pears", "Oranges"],
  b: ["Apples", "Oranges"]
};`). As it is accessed inside the context `{{#each a}}`, the path needs to be pointed to the parent. Thus using `../`.

Comment: I see, so in the `{{each}}` block you have to jump up a level to have access to the b object?

Comment: Also, refer `Handlebars Paths` in http://handlebarsjs.com. 
It says "Nested handlebars paths can also include ../ segments, which evaluate their paths against a parent context."

Comment: Yes you are right. Glad that I could help. You may upvote and/or mark the answer as correct one so that it would help other users. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> Alternative answer

As confirmed by OP, the real problem is due to the array being accessed incorrectly. The correct code is,

```
{{#inArray ../searchParams.a this}}
```